# Creating branch-and-bound

Tags: diagrams, forest

I want to create a graph like the one I give below! I think I should use forest package but it does not allow me (or I could not do it) to put explanations near each branch, like "solve as continuous problem".  Any help would be greatly appeciated.

[image]

Comment: You should at least provide the community with something to start with, rather than leaving them to construct something from scratch. Have you laid the foundation work for this already?

Comment: I am sorry for that, I am just so new at creating diagrams at Latex. I just could not figure it out! Of course, I worked on it! I created small diagrams! but when I do almost the same with this graph, there are so many errors I am getting and nodes are overlapping sometimes! As said, I am so new, I am learning!

Comment: It is much less work to take the content you've got and fix it than to copy it from an image. If you've worked on it, you at least have the content of the nodes. Indeed, you say that the only problem is creating the descriptions. Those are very easy to add using `edge label`. Post the code, and I can add the descriptions in a minute or two and provide an answer. I don't have time to start from scratch at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution using library `positioning` and `shapes.multipart`, `\textA,\textB,...,\textG` contain nodes text just change it as you need.

To split node in two parts we have `rectangle split` and `rectangle split parts=` from `shapes.multipart` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}


\def\textA{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\
subject to\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots}

\def\textB{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\
subject to\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots
\nodepart{two}
{\scriptsize $x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}
}

\def\textC{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\
subject to\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots
\nodepart{two}
{\scriptsize $x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}
}

\def\textD{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\
subject to\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots
\nodepart{two}
{\scriptsize $x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}}

\def\textE{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\
subject to\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots
\nodepart{two}
{\scriptsize $x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}}

\def\textF{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\
subject to\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots
\nodepart{two}
{\scriptsize $x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}}

\def\textG{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\
subject to\\
\hspace{1cm}\vdots
\nodepart{two}
{\scriptsize $x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}}

\tikzset{>=stealth,parent node/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,align=left,text width=2.5cm,draw,node distance=1cm and 1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[parent node,rectangle split parts=1](A){\textA};
\node[parent node,below =of A](B){\textB};
\node[parent node,below left =of B](C){\textC};
\node[parent node,below right =of B](D){\textD};
\node[parent node,node distance=1 and 0.3,below left =of C](E){\textE};
\node[parent node,node distance=1 and 0.3,below right =of C](F){\textF};
\node[parent node,node distance=1 and 0.3,below =of E](G){\textG};

\draw[->](A.south)--(B)node[midway,right]{\scriptsize solve as continous problem};
\draw[->](B.south)--+(0,-0.5)-|(D)node[right,near end]{\scriptsize $x_1\geq 2$};
\draw[->](B.south)--+(0,-0.5)-|(C)node[left,near end]{\scriptsize $x_1\leq 1$};
\draw[->](C.south)--+(0,-0.5)-|(E)node[left,near end]{\scriptsize $x_2\leq 2$};
\draw[->](C.south)--+(0,-0.5)-|(F)node[right,near end]{\scriptsize $x_2\geq $};
\draw[->](E.south)--(G)node[left,midway]{\scriptsize $x_1\geq 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Branch and Bound Methode Example:Integer bound of $x_1$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir! I really appreciate it but I am getting an error while I am running it! the error comes from the "\textA" (and the others) part!

Comment: @Oceansoul Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using the content kindly provided by [salim bou](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275605/), which the OP refused to supply, here are two Forest versions. Note, however, that I do not really think Forest is the best choice here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\tikzset{%
  >=stealth,
  parent node/.style={%
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    align=left,
    text width=2.5cm,
    draw,
    node distance=1cm and 1cm
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  %forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    inner xsep=0pt,
    align={l},
    edge={-Stealth},
    l sep+=20pt,
    %fork sep+=10pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where level=0{}{
      split option={content}{:}{temptoksa,temptoksb},
      content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={#1\\\hline #2}{temptoksa}{temptoksb},
      if={(n()==1)&&(level()>1)}{%
        edge label/.wrap value={%
          node [midway, left, font=\scriptsize] {#1}%
        },
      }{%
        edge label/.wrap value={%
          node [midway, right, font=\scriptsize] {#1}%
        },
      },
    },
  }
  [$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\subject to\\\dots
    [{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\subject to\\\dots}:{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={solve as continuous problem}
      [{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\subject to\\\dots}:{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_1\geq 2$}
       [{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\subject to\\\dots}:{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_1\leq 1$}
         [{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\subject to\\\dots}:{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_2\leq 2$}
         ]
       ]
       [{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\subject to\\\dots}:{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_2\geq 7$}
       ]
     ]
      [{$\text{min}\  x_1-2x_2$\\subject to\\\dots}:{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_1\geq 1$}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Standard version:

[image: standard tree]

Forked edges:

[image: forked edges]

For the second version, uncomment the two commented lines in the tree's preamble.