# Creating Branch&Bound

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I am trying to modify the answer provided by [@cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275563/creating-branch-and-bound#new-answer?newreg=2faa574ba7594dfea143146cbd34e4d2). However, there are strange content "height" in my result, see each box. Could anyone help me resolve this?

My code is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\tikzset{%
  >=stealth,
  parent node/.style={%
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    align=center,
    text width=2.5cm,
    draw,
    node distance=1cm and 1cm
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  %forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    inner xsep=1pt,
    edge={-Stealth},
    l sep+=20pt,
    %fork sep+=10pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where level=0{}{
      split option={content}{:}{temptoksa,temptoksb},
      content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={#1\\\hline #2}{temptoksa}{temptoksb},
      if={(n()==1)&&(level()>1)}{%
        edge label/.wrap value={%
          node [midway, left, font=\scriptsize] {#1}%
        },
      }{%
        edge label/.wrap value={%
          node [midway, right, font=\scriptsize] {#1}%
        },
      },
    },
  }
  [$ILO$
    [{}, edge label={solve as continuous problem}
      [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.166$}, edge label={$x_1\geq 2$}
       [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_1\leq 1$}
         [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_2\leq 2$}
         ]
       ]
       [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_2\geq 7$}
       ]
     ]
      [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_1\geq 1$}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

And my result is
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a minimal document with your question. Your code doesn't compile without errors for me; the output you're seeing is caused by Overleaf pushing through and creating some sort of output no matter what. The error is caused by the `\hline` in the code. Remove it, and you should get proper output.

Comment: My answer there expects a tree where most of the nodes have a colon and should be split in two for further processing.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you just need the edge label code, and not the code that splits the node label into two parts with a line between the parts (as in the linked answer.) In which case, this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\tikzset{%
  >=stealth,
  parent node/.style={%
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    align=center,
    text width=2.5cm,
    draw,
    node distance=1cm and 1cm
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  %forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    inner xsep=1pt,
    edge={-Stealth},
    l sep+=20pt,
    %fork sep+=10pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where level=0{}{
      if={(n()==1)&&(level()>1)}{%
        edge label/.wrap value={%
          node [midway, left, font=\scriptsize] {#1}%
        },
      }{%
        edge label/.wrap value={%
          node [midway, right, font=\scriptsize] {#1}%
        },
      },
    },
  }
  [$ILO$
    [{}, edge label={solve as continuous problem}
      [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.166$}, edge label={$x_1\geq 2$}
       [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_1\leq 1$}
         [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_2\leq 2$}
         ]
       ]
       [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_2\geq 7$}
       ]
     ]
      [{$x_1^*=1,x_2^*=2.1667$}, edge label={$x_1\geq 1$}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you so much!